# Multidemensional array only showing the final loop of one array working

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following:

```
$array = array ( 
    'success' => 'true', 
    'id' => $id, 
    'amount' => $amount, 
    'branches' => array ( 
        'branch' => array (
            'branch-id' => 1, 
            'branch-name' => 'Branch Name', 
            'branch-address' => 'Address',
            'branch-postcode' => 'Postcode' 
        ),
        'branch' => array (
            'branch-id' => 2, 
            'branch-name' => 'Branch Name', 
            'branch-address' => 'Address',
            'branch-postcode' => 'Postcode' 
        )
    ),
```

However, when printing the array, under branches, it only shows the second branch, not the first.

Comment: That's because there can only be one key called `branch`.

Comment: What an idiot! Cheers @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Your words, not mine! 

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$array = array ( 
    'success' => 'true', 
    'id' => $id, 
    'amount' => $amount, 
    'branches' => array ( 
        array (
            'branch-id' => 1, 
            'branch-name' => 'Branch Name', 
            'branch-address' => 'Address',
            'branch-postcode' => 'Postcode' 
        ),
        array (
            'branch-id' => 2, 
            'branch-name' => 'Branch Name', 
            'branch-address' => 'Address',
            'branch-postcode' => 'Postcode' 
        )
    )
);
```

This will number the branches; 0, 1, 2, 3, etc...

Personally I prefer a more modern syntax:

```
$array = ['success'  => 'true', 
          'id'       => $id, 
          'amount'   => $amount, 
          'branches' => [['branch-id'       => 1, 
                          'branch-name'     => 'Branch Name', 
                          'branch-address'  => 'Address',
                          'branch-postcode' => 'Postcode'],
                         ['branch-id'       => 2, 
                          'branch-name'     => 'Branch Name', 
                          'branch-address'  => 'Address',
                          'branch-postcode' => 'Postcode']]];
```

and you could also use the `'branch-id'` as the keys for the branches:

```
$array = ['success'  => 'true', 
          'id'       => $id, 
          'amount'   => $amount, 
          'branches' => [1 => ['branch-name'     => 'Branch Name', 
                               'branch-address'  => 'Address',
                               'branch-postcode' => 'Postcode'],
                         2 => ['branch-name'     => 'Branch Name', 
                               'branch-address'  => 'Address',
                               'branch-postcode' => 'Postcode']]];
```